# C# | How to pass a parameter from View to DAL (via layers)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, controller, n-tier-architecture

I am working on a project where I need to give the user the option to type their most wanted kind of character (that can be defensive, offensive, recon, support).
That string that they have typed in a textfield in my view should be converted (I think in my controller) to a parameter. This parameter can be passed to my DAL layer (via my logic layer). In my DAL layer I can put the parameter into my getcharacter method so the user only gets the characters in the database where the input is the same as the character kind.
(note: in the code you will see Karakter in stead of Character. That is because that is Dutch)

**This is my database:**
[image]

**My DAL:**

```cs
public IEnumerable<IKarakter> GetSortedKarakters(string inputKarakterSoort)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Karakter WHERE KarakterSoort = @inputKarakterSoort ORDER BY NEWID();", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@inputKarakterSoort", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = inputKarakterSoort;
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var sortedKarakters = new List<IKarakter>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var karakter = new KarakterDTO
            {
                KarakterId = (int)reader["KarakterId"],
                KarakterSoort = reader["KarakterSoort"]?.ToString(),
                KarakterNaam = reader["KarakterNaam"]?.ToString()
            };
            sortedKarakters.Add(karakter);
        }
        return sortedKarakters;
    }
}
```

**My Logic layer:**

```cs
public class SortedKarakterLogic : ISortedKarakterLogic
{
    private ISortedKarakterContext sortedKarakterContext { get; }
    
    public SortedKarakterLogic(ISortedKarakterContext sortedContext)
    {
        sortedKarakterContext = sortedContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IKarakter> GetSortedKarakters(string inputKarakterSoort)
    {
        return sortedKarakterContext.GetSortedKarakters(inputKarakterSoort);
    }
}
```

**My VieuwLayer:**

**My controller:**

```cs
public class SortedKaraktersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISortedKarakterLogic _sortedKarakterLogic;
    
    public SortedKaraktersController()
    {
        _sortedKarakterLogic = ApexFactory.ApexFactory.GetSortedKarakterLogic();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult SortedKarakter(string karakterSoort)
    {
        var sortedKarakters = _sortedKarakterLogic.GetSortedKarakters(karakterSoort);
        var _sortedKarakters = new List<KarakterViewModel>();
        foreach (var karakter in sortedKarakters)
        {
            _sortedKarakters.Add(new KarakterViewModel
            {
                KarakterId = karakter.KarakterId,
                KarakterNaam = karakter.KarakterNaam,
                KarakterSoort = karakter.KarakterSoort
            }) ;
        }
        return View(_sortedKarakters);
    }
}
```

**My cs.html:**

```cs
using (Html.BeginForm("SortedKarakter", "SortedKarakters"))
{
    <input type="text" name="karakterSoort" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

---

The error that I get when I run this is:

```
SqlException: SqlException: SqlException: The parameterized query '(@inputKarakterSoort varchar(8000))SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Karakter ' expects the parameter '@inputKarakterSoort', which was not supplied.
```

I know that this error is located in my DAL, but I don't know if I need to fix it in my DAL because I tried to set the parameter of the GetSortedKarakters class (in my DAL) to a string like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<IKarakter> GetSortedKarakters(string inputKarakterSoort)
{
    inputKarakterSoort = "Defensive"
```

And the database returned only the characters with Defensive as character kind (or KarakterSoort in the database), which is what I want.

So the comment suggested that I put a breakpoint in my controller to see if my parameter karakterSoort is null, and it is.

What should I change (probably in my cs.html) so it passes the value given in the textbox instead of null?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what the value of `inputKarakterSoort` is?  My best guess is that you might be passing a null value.

Comment: Your right! What should I do?

Comment: What view you use for My cs.html and show us the action you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Create viewModelClass:

```
 public class InputKarakterSoortViewModel
{
 public string InputKarakterSoort {get; set;} 
}
```

Create get action

```
[Route("~/SortedKarakter/GetInputKarakterSoort")]
public ActionResult GetInputKarakterSoort ()
{
    var viewModel= new InputKarakterSoortViewModel{InputKarakterSoort = "Defensive"};
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Use this code for your view

```
@model InputKarakterSoortViewModel
......
using (Html.BeginForm("SortedKarakter", "SortedKarakters"))
{
    <input type="text" asp-for="InputKarakterSoort" name="InputKarakterSoort" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

And change your action code:

```
public ActionResult SortedKarakter([FromForm] InputKarakterSoortViewModel viewModel)
{
    var karakterSoort = viewModel.InputKarakterSoort;

.........
.......

}
```

There are several much more simplier ways but  you have to use javascript ajax code .

Comment: In your ActionResult GetInputKarakterSoort you set InputKarakterSoort equal to the string defensive, while it should be equal to the user input, not to a value that is set by me. How would I do that?

Comment: This set  makes "Defencive" as a default value of InputKarakterSoort . When the view is created it will be a value or  <input type="text" asp-for="InputKarakterSoort" name="InputKarakterSoort" />. User then can change it or leave it . Or just remove InputKarakterSoort = "Defensive" if you want user to get an empty input.